# Issue passing props to component in REACT

Tags: javascript, reactjs

EDIT: Issue was with the condition. Thank you guys!

I am designing a covid19 watcher application using an open source API. I log out the state to see if it updates, which it does, but when I pass the state to a component, it doesn't get the data passed.

So I put in a condition on the render() and it seems the state doesn't update so the component doesn't get it. Maybe because componentDidMount runs after render has. How do I fix it?

App.js

```js
import React from 'react';
import Homepage from './pages/homepage/homepage.component.jsx';
import './App.css';

class App extends React.Component{
  constructor(){
    super()
    this.state = {
      statistics:{},
    }
  }

   componentDidMount(){
    fetch('https://api.covid19api.com/summary')
    .then(response => response.json())
    .then(data => {
      const all_data = data;
      this.setState({statistics: all_data});
      console.log(this.state);
      })
  }


  render(){
    const { statistics } = this.state;
      return !statistics.length ? 
        <div> Some text </div> :
      (
      <Homepage statistics={statistics} />
      );  
  }
}
export default App;
```

Comment: The data you're grabbing has no `length` property, so `statistics.length` is `undefined`. I suggest using a debugger to examine the values of your variables, etc. The data provided is not an array.

Comment: Your code is also falling prey to the footgun in the `fetch` API: You aren't checking for HTTP success before calling `json` (`fetch` only rejects its promise on *network* failure, not HTTP failure). Details in [this post](http://blog.niftysnippets.org/2018/06/common-fetch-errors.html) on my anemic little blog. Separately, if an error *does* occur, your code has nothing to handle rejection of the promise.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder Thanks for the information about the length. Concerning the fetch, doesn't the console.log serve as a form of check in this case? Because it actually does log out the state with the data I'm trying to get with the fetch.

Comment: I just meant in general, not specific to the problem you're trying to diagnose. The HTTP success check should be in the code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`statistics` is an object, it doesn't have a `length` property. To check if you have something in `statistics` you can use `Object.keys` on that object:

```
return !Object.keys(statistics).length ?
```

`Object.keys(statistics)` returns an array of the object keys, so if your object is empty, it will return an empty array

By the way, in your `componentDidMount`, when you do:

```
  this.setState({statistics: all_data});
  console.log(this.state);
```

setState is asynchronous, so console.log won't work

Comment: Thank you so much! Now it shows that there's something in statistics but my Homepage component can use it.

Answer (score 1):

I believe the issue has nothing to do with the child component.

`ComponentDidUpdate` lifecycle method does run after render, but as the state is being updated it triggers the render to run again with the new state.

The problem is your condition.
As the API returns an object and not an array it doesn't have the length property so your condition always is true and render the `<div> Nawa oh </div>` element.

You should instead check if the state is an empty object or if the state has keys

```
return statistics === {} ? 
        <div> Nawa oh </div> :
      (
      <Homepage statistics={statistics} />
      ); 
// Or a better way to check if statistics has keys
return Object.keys(statistics).length ? (
      <Homepage statistics={statistics} />
      ) : <div> Nawa oh </div>;
```